# Реализация записи и мониторинга веса человека в приложении

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В данный момент занимаюсь разработкой приложения для занятий спортом (пока только учусь). Подскажите как лучше было бы реализовать запись веса человека, мониторинг (то есть по отношению к каждой предыдущей записи что бы выводился подсчет сколько человек набрал или скинул).Лучше записывать эти данные в файл или бд?В общем буду рада любым идеям.

Comment: Необходимо конкретизировать вопрос, т.к. в текущем варианте он слишком общий. Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Comment: лучше писать в БД, так как в дальнейшем это вам сильно поможет со статистикой: подсчет среднего, выборка за период и т. п. С хранением в файле все это будет крайне нелепо обрабатываться

Comment: @pavlofff, а как тогда лучше поступить, к примеру я представляю как реализовать при нажатии кнопки запись данных о весе в бд, далее эти данные с помощью другой кнопки выводить в новой активности. А возможно сделать при нажатии на одну кнопку, что бы данные и записывались и тут же выводилась новая активность с этими данными?

Comment: конечно. если вы знаете, как сделать каждое действие отдельно, просто сделайте два действия по нажатии одной кнопки (перенесите код, выполняющийся по нажатии второй кнопки после кода по нажатии первой). Если вы не можете самостоятельно решить эту проблему, задайте новый вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы делаете приложение **только** для обучения то реализация зависит от того, что вам интереснее изучить, иначе делайте через БД.

- Для реализации БД попробуйте [ROOM](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html).
- Если хотите попробовать хранить в файле то можно через [сериализацию](https://riptutorial.com/ru/android/example/27106/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)